# Can't install gnome-session on lubuntu 12.04

Tags: gnome, lubuntu

I did a clean install of **Lubuntu 12.04** and I want to install the gnome3-session

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session
```

Then I logged out. When I login on to the gnome-session I’m still getting the unity-layout.

Have I done something wrong? If so what do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: do you want to remove unity completely?

Answer (score 1):

I replaced Unity with Gnome in the following steps

1. Install Gnome

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
   ```
2. To set gnome-shell as default, open a terminal and type

   ```
   sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s gnome-shell
   ```
3. And to remove `unity` after installing `gnome-shell`

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove unity unity-2d unity-2d-panel unity-2d-shell
   ```

Comment: Thx
I did the job ;)

Comment: did my solution work? if it did plz mark it as the correct answer